# Can I install the memcached PHP extension with PECL?

Tags: php, macos, memcached, pecl

I'm having trouble installing the "[memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached)" PHP extension from PECL, though I can successfully installed the "[memcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache)" extension. (They are separate PHP extensions.)

For example, these commands work okay:

> $ sudo pecl install memcache
>   $ sudo pecl install APC
>   $ sudo pecl install oauth

However, attempting to install memcached causes errors:

> $ sudo pecl install memcached
>   ...
>   ld: library not found for -lmemcached
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [memcached.la] Error 1
>   ERROR: `make' failed

I'm using pecl, memcached, and libmemcached from Mac Ports (macports.org) on a recent Intel Mac. The libmemcached libraries can be found in /opt/local:

> /opt/local/include/libmemcached
>   /opt/local/include/libmemcached/libmemcached_config.h
>   /opt/local/lib/libmemcached.2.0.0.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libmemcached.2.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libmemcached.a
>   /opt/local/lib/libmemcached.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libmemcached.la

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Andrei Zmievski (developer of the memcached plugin) kindly answered my email request with the following instructions:

```
$ pecl download memcached
$ tar zxvf memcached-1.0.0.tgz (or whatever version downloads)
$ cd memcached-1.0.0
$ phpize
$ ./configure --with-libmemcached-dir=/opt/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This worked perfectly.

Comment: What is /opt/local a reference to? I don't understand this part.

Comment: For memcache (and not memcached) with MAMP 1.9 i had to use this way to configure:  `./configure --prefix=/Applications/MAMP/ --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php-config`

Comment: @ChrisHarrison: /opt/local is the location of MacPorts (though I'm now using Brew.)

Comment: Man, the hoops you need to go through. Anyway, the above solution worked for me (using libmemcached 1.0.10 and memcached 2.1.0), with some additional steps: doing a "sudo port install libmemcached" first, and then adding "extensions=memcached.so" to my /private/etc/php.ini and doing a "sudo apachectl restart" for good measure.

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

Answer (score 2):

same situation here. i had to do the above, but with explicit path names (i run my php etc. out of /opt/local)

- **/opt/local/bin**/pecl download memcached
- tar zxvf memcached-1.0.0.tgz
- cd memcached-1.0.0
- **/opt/local/bin**/phpize
- ./configure **--prefix=/opt/local --with-php-config=/opt/local/bin/php-config** --with-libmemcached-dir=/opt/local
- make
- make install

normally this kind of stuff is pretty simple on os x with macports, but there is no php5-memcached package yet (only one for the older, memcache (no "d") package). oh, an i also had to install an older version of libmemcached, since the latest version didn't compile on os x 10.5.8 for me. oy!

Comment: For others, I was able to use this for 'memcache' (not memcache*d*) for PHP 8.0 on a Mac still running Catalina (10.15.7) over a decade later. I don't have /opt/local/bin/ but you can compile it wherever you like, e.g. /usr/local/src/ and it will automatically put it in a directory such as /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.23_1/pecl/20200930/

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, the new memcached extension, uses libmemcached to do the heavy lifting. If it were Linux, I'd say that it was possible that you don't have /opt/local/lib/ listed in ld.so.conf (and run 'ldconfig').

MaxOSX doesn't use that though.  It is, however installable from 'ports' apparently. http://lsimons.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/serious-php-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many tries only this solution works for me.

1. Install XAMPP
2. Install brew (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation)
3. $ brew
4. install libmemcached
5. cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/
6. $ sudo ./pecl install memcached

> Build process completed successfully Installing
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/memcached.so'
>   install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/memcached-2.2.0 configuration
>   option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location You should add
>   "extension=memcached.so" to php.ini

VOILA !!