# Having huge problems getting memcached plugin working on ub 9.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, memcached, libmemcache

Heya, so I've spent about 6 hours now trying to get this working. I had the following set of rules I uses to compile in the memcached plugin to php, installing libmemcached dependency first. Here are the steps:

```
cd ~  
sudo wget http://download.tangent.org/libmemcached-0.35.tar.gz  
sudo tar -zxf libmemcached-0.35.tar.gz  
cd libmemcached-0.35  
sudo ./configure  
sudo make  
sudo make install  
cd /usr/lib  
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so  
sudo pecl install memcached  
sudo rm -r ~/libmemcached-0.35  
sudo rm ~/libmemcached-0.35.tar.gz  
php.ini-edit
```

Search for `Dynamic Extensions` and add in the extension `memcached.so`. Do this by adding:     extension=”memcached.so”
:wq

It used to work; last time I rebuilt my box was back in Feb or March, but I've heard that since then there are some changes that go on. When I run `sudo make` above I get some erroring out. I'm not sure if I included the error anyone could help me debug, so does anyone have a set of instructions they used to get memcached working properly on their ub box? With the libmemcached dependency?

I've seen this: [Can I install the memcached PHP extension with PECL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683864/can-i-install-the-memcached-php-extension-with-pecl)

The author of memcached basically told the guy how to do, but I've tried that to no avail. Help with be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get -y install g++
wget http://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/0.39/+download/libmemcached-0.39.tar.gz
tar zxvf libmemcached-0.39.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-0.39/
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so
sudo pecl install memcached
sudo rm -r ~/libmemcached-0.39
sudo rm ~/libmemcached-0.39.tar.gz
php.ini-edit
```

Search for `Dynamic Extensions` and add in the extension `memcached.so`

```
:wq
```