# pecl install memcache fails on OS X Yosemite with "memcache support requires ZLIB"

Tags: php, macos, memcached, libmemcache

I'm trying to perform a `pecl install memcache` with XAMPP on OS X Yosemite, but it fails to find `zlib`, producing this error:

> checking for the location of ZLIB... no 
>   checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: memcache support requires ZLIB. 
>   Use --with-zlib-dir= to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
>       ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes' failed

How to I install `zlib` so that this `pecl install memcache` can succeed?

Comment: Please format the question properly

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Also, I feel your question is more appropriate on Server Fault. Please consider migrate your question.

Comment: Clarified the question, formatted the command output and eliminated unnecessary detail so reader doesn't have to scroll, improved title to state actual problem

Comment: `brew install zlib` and then try again.

Comment: I don't agree about moving this to server fault. OSX is an environment that's commonly used for development therefore developers will face this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
brew install zlib
```

If you haven't already done so

Next find the zlib headers:

```
locate zlib.h
```

You may find you have a few options to choose from.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/ etc
```

or

```
/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8/include/zlib.h
```

I use brew wherever I can so I chose the brew version:

```
brew install php55-memcached --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.8/include/zlib.h
```

I assume passing this flag to pecl will have the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with another extension ([SPX](https://github.com/NoiseByNorthwest/php-spx))

`checking for zlib header... checking for zlib location... configure: error: spx support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify the prefix where ZLIB headers and library are located`

I did fix it when running `./configure` using the `--with-zlib-dir` flag. Make sure what you have zlib installed (`brew install zlib`).

```
phpize

# replace "./configure" with:
./configure --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.13
# or "--with-zlib-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.2.13" for Apple silicon

make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Also, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279105/763419 is a longer step-by-step walkthrough for downloading a module and compiling it. (And neither mentions using ``locate zlib.h`` to find the correct directory, if anyone is struggling with that.)